# Espresso testing with never ending AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, signalr, android-espresso

I am trying to run an Espresso test under real conditions in my app. Problem is that tests never run because `Espresso` cannot detect an idle state in order to inject it's event to queue. Therefore it hangs and ends with known `ASYNC_TASKS_HAVE_IDLED` error.

Why this happens?

The application is using `SignalR` library and it is initialized on app start. ["Library GitHub url"](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client). This library creates multiple long polling connections in order to send and receive all kind of messages and events to/from the server.

These connections are implemented with `AsyncTask` ([class url](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/blob/master/signalr-client-sdk-android/src/main/java/microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client/http/android/AndroidHttpConnection.java)) and since they end rarely (and when they do, they are restarted instantly), Espresso has very little chance to detect `idle` state and continue the execution.

So, is there some workaround for this problem? Am I really forced to switch to `UIAutomator` because of this?

Notes:

- Disabling the SignalR is not an option (tried, tests work but then I'm missing the point of the app)
- Mocking the SignalR is also not an option. I want to test the real data.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

I also have many Async. tasks on my app..
So what I do is :

1. Registered idling resource.
2. Made it false when I need to stop/wait.
3. Made it true when I want to proceed.
4. But when there is a lot of calls then this won't work. Else it works fine in my simple cases.

---

```
@Before
    public void registerIdlingResource() {
        Utils.idle = true;
        mIdlingResource = mActivityRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);

}

-----------------------------

 @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
        if (mIdlingResource != null) {
            Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
        }
    }


-------------------
signIn();
Utils.idle = false;
onView(withId(R.id.ll_reports)).perform(click());
Utils.idle = false;
```

After sign in method i wait until the mail page is loaded. Then I click on my layout with id ll_reports. Then again I wait for next task that I want to perform.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Idling resource is one of the common paths to follow in this case, but unfortunately, I don't have an access to source of the library, hence unable to register or unregister the idling resource.
I think that case from above does not have a proper solution.